# Unable to load spacy models in conda

Tags: python, spacy

I am trying to load "en_core_web_sm" this model but getting the error. I tried downloading the model from conda repository but then error got changed.
Before installing the package

[E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

but when I write "import en_core_web_sm" and after that, I try to load model I get a different error.

could not broadcast input array from shape (96) into shape (128).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like the model you downloaded is not compatible with the spaCy version you're using. Try running `python -m spacy validate` to check for incompatibility issues. More info here: https://spacy.io/usage/#installation

Comment: sure, run `conda activate my_spacy_env` first, changing the instruction to point to your specific conda environment where you have spaCy installed, then run the `validate` command.